# Python 3 : NameError: name 'functionName' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in programming and I have faced a problem for which I can't find an answer... So here it is:

```
`class MyClass:
    def printsmth():
        print("Hello")
    def main():
        printsmth()
    if __name__ == '__main__':main()`
```

I get an error which says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    class MyClass:
  File "untitled.py", line 6, in MyClass
    if __name__ == '__main__':main()
  File "untitled.py", line 5, in main
    printsmth()
NameError: name 'printsmth' is not defined
```

Code included is just an example, but it is the same error that I get on my real code, if for example I would transfer my code from main() to if **name** == '**main**' than it works perfectly. The thing is that I want to relaunch main() method in some parts of the code but I haven't even gone to that because I can't think of a solution to this error:/ Can you help me?

P.S I tried to move main() and if **name** == '**main**' from MyClass and it didn't worked.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces - you need to get familiar with essential Python concepts (in this case scopes).

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to write Java in python. That is the only reason I can think of for unbound functions inside a `class`. Follow any python tutorial of the thousands  out there for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to pass `self` as the first parameter of your methods.  Once you do this, you can call`self.printsmth()` as a method.  Right now it's confused because you're calling it as a function rather than a method.

```
class MyClass:
    def printsmth(self):
        print("Hello")
    def main(self):
        self.printsmth()
```